# Display object inside of array inside Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to display the object name of a the suppliers array but i'm confused because its inside an array. I'm display the array and also i want to display the object name of the second array. But the problem is on the second array. The supplier.name is i want to display it. The pic is below

[PICTURE IS HERE][1]

> ts

```
 getAllMaterials() {
    this.subscription = this.materialsService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.materials = data.materials;
            let suppliers = data.materials[0].suppliers;
            console.log(data);
            console.log(suppliers);
          },
          error => {
           alert("Error");
           console.log(error);
          });
  }
```

> html

```
<tr *ngFor="let material of materials">
                  <td>{{ material.sku }}</td>
                  <td>{{ material.name }}</td>
                  <td>display on this td</td>
                  <td>{{ material.price }}</td>
                  <td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the length of your supplier rray will always be one ? or you want to display multiple td's there?

Comment: @vertika I want to display the suppliers.name in one td

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can do two things :

**Solution 1 :** If you have only single record in suppliers

```
<tr *ngFor="let material of materials">
              <td>{{ material.sku }}</td>
              <td>{{ material.name }}</td>
              <td>{{material.suppliers[0].name}}</td>
              <td>{{ material.price }}</td>
              <td>
</tr>
```

**Solution 2 :**

If you want to show multiple names in same td :

```
 <tr *ngFor="let material of materials">
              <td>{{ material.sku }}</td>
              <td>{{ material.name }}</td>
              <td><span *ngFor ="let s of material.suppliers"> {{s.name}} 
               </span>
              </td>
              <td>{{ material.price }}</td>
              <td>
</tr>
```